# Что значит шаблонный класс на основе другого класса или списка?

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Что значит шаблонный класс на основе другого класса или списка? Тупой возможно вопрос,но не могу въехать что значит шаблон класса на основе какой либо структуры или другого класса.

Comment: Вам нужен пример шаблонного класса?

Answer (score 5):

Представьте себе [**абстрактную структуру данных список.**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) Вполне очевидно, что *хорошо реализованный* список должен уметь элементы некоторого произвольного типа.

Т.е мы должны уметь сообщить компилятору, что, скажем, `объект A1` - это список для целых чисел, а `объект A2` - это список для вещественных чисел.

---

*Эквивалентно на `C++`:*

```
List<int> A1;
List<float> A2;
```

---

Однако понятно, что возможность использования шаблонизированных классов не заканчивается **целыми** или **вещественными** типами. Легко можно представить себе список, в котором элементом является **другой список целых чисел.**

Это будет записано следующим образом и как раз и является примером шаблона на основе какого-либо другого класса *(в данном случае, на основе `List<int>`)*.

```
List<List<int> > A3;
```

Понятно, что идеологически все примеры - это некоторые частные случаи `List<Object>`.

Comment: Спасибо большое очень внятно))